# which git commands should i choose to commit?

Tags: git, github

i am a cs student and have got a question from my homework:

Person A has made 2 changes to his programm
1. interface unnamed: IFoo->IBar, class name changed:Foo->Bar
2. add a function blob() to the interface
he has forgotten to commit. and he doesn't wanna a big commit, but 2 separate commits.

how could he do? which command should he use?

thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add -i` will open an interactive shell and allow you to choose what rows in what files you want to stage. Once they're changed, you can commit them.